# 2 Columns with Fixed - Scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 columns and I need the first to be fixed, where the second has a long list and needs to be scrollable.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

The `Col-md-9` has the long list, and the `Col-md-3` needs to be `fixed`. I've been trying for a while now to get this working but things keep breaking all the time.

When I try to `position:fixed`, the col-md-3 floats automatically left.
I tried to give everything width's and even removed the grid system from Bootstrap but I can't get it working.

I could hard code it like:

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="float: left;width: 100%;margin-right: 243px">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="float: right;width: 243px;position: fixed;margin-left: 728px">
```

but this breaks responsiveness like hell...

@Edu Lomeli pointed out [Affix Js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). As the Bootstrap Documentation:

> The subnavigation on the right is a live demo of the affix plugin.

and that's the EXACT behavior I'm looking for. The problem is I don't understand it fully.

Comment: So any reason to use Twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, the whole app is build with Bootstrap !

Comment: There are couple of styles applied to the columns by default, such as `float`. These may conflict with what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried to float left-right but it's not working.

Comment: Not sure if this are you want to achieve, but you can try using [Affix JS](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with Affix JS and by moving the Col-md-3 to the left

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look -----> [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/82661#)

Answer (score 0):

You need some extra definitions for `position:fixed`. To manage the left - right position for that element now, you have to use `right`,`left`,`top`,`bottom` css ports. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="position:fixed; top: 0; right: 0;"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is i'm using this inside a container and .row.. With top/right: 0 it pushes it to the display corner..